# How to filter ACTION_SEND intent with only facebook and facebook messenger and whatsapp

Tags: android

How can you filter out specific apps when using the ACTION_SEND intent? This question has been asked in various ways, but I haven't been able to gather a solution based on the answers given. Hopefully someone can help. I would like to provide the ability to share within an app.
like this picture! https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS6n6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have no control on what app will be available, you need to hardode this dialog by yourself, and then depending on the choice of the user, launch the ACTION_SEND intent specifically.

Explanations from this website : http://clickclickclack.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/intercepting-androids-action_send-intents/

Create an Activity "ShareActivity" displaying a layout with a ListView.
Implement then the Adapter as follow :

```
public class ShareIntentListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    Activity context;
    Object[] items;
    boolean[] arrows;
    int layoutId;

    public ShareIntentListAdapter(Activity context, int layoutId, Object[] items) {
        super(context, layoutId, items);

        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.layoutId = layoutId;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        label.setText(((ResolveInfo)items[pos]).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString());
        ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        image.setImageDrawable(((ResolveInfo)items[pos]).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager()));

        return(row);
    }
}
```

Then in your "ShareActivity", inflate the listView, create an array containing what you want to display for each intent you want (i.e logo/name/whatever else for FB, FB Messenger, Twitter etc...), and then create the ShareIntentListAdapter with this array and attach it to the listView.

Final step will be to handle the onClick method, to get the item clicked and launch the intent selected.

Comment: but how to make context menu or dialog with icon like the picture attached

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial to create the listView and populate it with whatever application you want : 
http://clickclickclack.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/intercepting-androids-action_send-intents/

Comment: this example doesn't show how to populate  the listview after click button

Comment: "Now this is when the magic happens. Rather than launching the action_send intent and letting it create its own dialog [one that we would have no control over], we will build our own with the AlertDialog.Builder. First we give it a title, then set its adapter to the list adapter we just created with the activities list as our data set [list adapter code posted at the end of the article, but there is nothing special about it]."

The list is being populated via the last source code `public class ShareIntentListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Please I can't fined the code that populate the listview please tell me in details what i write in onclick() to lunch the listview

Answer (score 0):

as @NSimon answer I got it by hardoding this dialog by myself, and then depending on the choice of the user, launch the ACTION_SEND intent specifically

```
public void ShareDialog_popualate() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.sharingBy));
    ListView list = new ListView(MainActivity.this);
    list.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    list.setAdapter(new SharingListAdapter(MainActivity.this));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (sharedialog.isShowing()) {
                sharedialog.dismiss();
            }
            IntentShareApp(position);
//              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
//                      "Clicked at Position" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
 //                     .show();
        }
    });
    builder.setView(list);
    sharedialog = builder.create();
    sharedialog.show();
}
```

and the cumstome class for listadapter  is

```
 package com.artgine.daleel;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

public class SharingListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater inflator;
String[]sharing_names={"Facebook","Whatsapp","Messenger"};
final int[] images = { R.drawable.share_icon,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.send_msg_icon_cancel,
         };
public SharingListAdapter(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
this.mContext=context;
this.inflator= (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MainListHolder mHolder;

    View v = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        mHolder = new MainListHolder();

        v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.share_items, null);
        mHolder.image=  (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgviewshareicon);
        mHolder.text=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.sharenamebtn); 
        v.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (MainListHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    mHolder.image.setImageResource(images[position]);
    mHolder.image.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    mHolder.text.setText(sharing_names[position]);
    return v;
}
class MainListHolder
{
    private ImageView image;
    private TextView text;
}
}
```

and to intetent actionsend as user choice

```
 public void IntentShareApp(int position) {
    String palystoreApplink = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
            + this.getPackageName();        
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will
    // decide
    // what to do with it.
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,palystoreApplink);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,getResources().getString(R.string.sharingBy)));

}
```